# AngularFire 0.9.0 post-login (auth) Binding

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

**Update**: per Kato's reply, I created example codes. [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765489/532517).

---

Simply copying the code at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication results in a working **[codepen](http://codepen.io/AngelEyesChina/pen/ZYBWQw)** ([here it is](https://gist.github.com/AngelEyesChina/de16e376a5eef17102b1#angularfire-090-auth) as a github gist) that logs me in/out, yet does not "refresh" the data, i.e. the expression `{{ user.facebook.displayName }}` is not really bound.

The question: **Is there a way to make the controller actually bind to the logged-in state?**

**Note I**: there is no direct link to the code on firebase.com, is the code that appears under the sentence

> Pulling some of these concepts together, we can create a login form
>   with dynamic content based on the user's authentication state

**Note II**: in order to make the copied code work, you have to replace the firebase url with your own.

**edit** - just discovered the "code snippet" feature:

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

// let's create a re-usable factory that generates the $firebaseAuth instance
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);

// and use it in our controller
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", function($scope, Auth) {
  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.user = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
}])
```

```html
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
    <div ng-show="user">
      <p>Hello, {{ user.facebook.displayName }}</p>
      <button ng-click="auth.$unauth()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="user">
      <p>Welcome, please log in.</p>
      <button ng-click="auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')">Login</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code. It's great that you took the effort to set up a codepen (I'll head over there next), but that is not a replacement for having the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the code is simply a bit lengthy - isn't the Github gist good enough?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I inserted the code as a snippet (and thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$getAuth() is a synchronous function call, as documented and explained. You need to utilize $onAuth() if you want it to update asynchronously each time the login state changes.

```
Auth.$onAuth(function(userData) {
   // $timeout needed for AngularFire 0.9.0
   // see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/510
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.user = userData;
   });
});
```

But really, you should be [using routes and the resolve method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes), so you don't have to deal with all this auth stuff in the scope and controllers, as explained in the docs just below the section you are reading now.

Comment: BTW, @Kato, I think it should be $scope.auth.$onAuth instead of $scope.$onAuth

Answer (score 0):

Per @Kato's answer, I created 2 examples (with snippets and codepens), for anyone who might get stuck there, as I did.

The first, simply shows that using $onAuth as shown by @Kato, will simulate the binding.
The second, is the same but also with ng-view to show usage with routes, per @Kato's advice.

First snippet: ([codepen here](http://codepen.io/AngelEyesChina/pen/QwGOmw))

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

// let's create a re-usable factory that generates the $firebaseAuth instance
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://glowing-inferno-4287.firebaseio.com/");
    //var ref = new Firebase("https://<replace-with-your-db-id>.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);

// and use it in our controller
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$timeout",
  function($scope, Auth, $timeout) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(userData) {
      // $timeout needed for AngularFire 0.9.0
      // see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/510
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.user = userData;
      });
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <div ng-show="user">
    <p>Hello, {{ user.facebook.displayName }}</p>
    <button ng-click="auth.$unauth()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="user">
    <p>Welcome, please log in.</p>
    <button ng-click="auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')">Login</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Second snippet: ([codepen here](http://codepen.io/AngelEyesChina/pen/WboXOV))

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase", "ngRoute"]);
// let's create a re-usable factory that generates the $firebaseAuth instance
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<replace-with-your-db-id>.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);

// and use it in our controller
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$timeout", "$location", "$route",
  function($scope, Auth, $timeout, $location, $route) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(userData) {
      // $timeout needed for AngularFire 0.9.0
      // see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/510
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.user = userData;
      });
      $route.reload();
    });

    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')
        .then(function() {
          $location.path("/account");
        });
    }
  }
]);

app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["Auth",
  function(Auth) {
    this.userData = Auth.$getAuth();
  }
]);

app.run(["$rootScope", "$location",
  function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
      // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
      // and redirect the user back to the home page
      if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
        $location.path("/");
      }
    });
  }
]);

app.config(["$routeProvider",
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
      // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
      templateUrl: "views/home.html",
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth",
          function(Auth) {
            // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
            return Auth.$waitForAuth();
          }
        ]
      }
    }).when("/account", {
      // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
      templateUrl: "views/account.html",
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth",
          function(Auth) {
            // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
            return Auth.$requireAuth();
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <div ng-show="user">
    <p>Hello, {{ user.facebook.displayName }}</p>
    <button ng-click="auth.$unauth()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="user">
    <p>Welcome, please log in.</p>
    <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/home.html">
    home template.
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/account.html">
    <div ng-controller="AccountCtrl as accntCtrl">
      account template.
      <br />Hello from account page, {{accntCtrl.userData.facebook.displayName}}
    </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```